Ansible: Search for string ending with specific format
I'm trying to filter a specific string ending in cmctl_linux_arm64, from the checksums.txt file, see sample:
ff5e6efc85421bc46975ee60cf71bec1de3f983f27a3ba8e56a0953e8c9b8a07  cmctl_linux_arm64
bb5b8db1da6b4f7f046ebbf0aced0623e1b93990c474beb525296e72076b9421  cmctl_linux_arm64.spdx.sbom
6f903b8554f7e608ba3d156878f3720480b5dd693400e0354f2c88b94e4b9de0  cmctl_linux_arm64.tar.gz

Considering the following tasks:
    - name: Set file fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        release_file: cmctl_linux_arm64
      run_once: true

    - name: Set checksums fact
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        url: https://github.com/cert-manager/cmctl/releases/download/v2.1.0/checksums.txt
        return_content: true
      register: checksums
      run_once: true

    - name: Set sha256 checksum fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        sha256_checksum: "{{ item.split(' ')[0] }}"
      loop: "{{ checksums.content.split('\n') }}"
      when: release_file in item
      run_once: true

I'm not sure how to use the Ansible Regex search, in order to define the end of fact variable release_file and skip the additional 2 file checksums present.
Edit: Using the following format fixes the issue:
when: item | regex_search(release_file + '$')

In contrast, I cannot use a select:
when: item | select('search', release_file + '$')

Or in:
when: item in regex_search(release_file + '$')

I'm wondering what is the correct way to write the condition.

Wasn't that not already answered with How to extract the checksum matching ...?

It is slightly different, since I use a regex search for a combination of variable concatenated with a string, as detailed above.

Put the regex into a variable
  regex: "^.*  {{ release_file }}$"
  result: "{{ checksums.content.split('\n') |
              select('regex', regex) |
              map('split') | map('first') }}"

gives
  result:
  - ff5e6efc85421bc46975ee60cf71bec1de3f983f27a3ba8e56a0953e8c9b8a07

Optionally, reverse the items. Then, match the pattern at the beginning of the strings. The below expression gives the same result
  result: "{{ checksums.content.split('\n') | map('reverse') |
              select('match', release_file|reverse) |
              map('reverse') | map('split') | map('first') }}"



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    release_file: cmctl_linux_arm64
    checksums:
      content: |-
        ff5e6efc8542  cmctl_linux_arm64
        bb5b8db1da6b  cmctl_linux_arm64.spdx.sbom
        6f903b8554f7  cmctl_linux_arm64.tar.gz

    regex: "^.*  {{ release_file }}$"
    result: "{{ checksums.content.split('\n') |
                select('regex', regex) |
                map('split') | map('first') }}"

    resul2: "{{ checksums.content.split('\n') | map('reverse') |
                select('match', release_file|reverse) |
                map('reverse') | map('split') | map('first') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result
    - debug:
        var: resul2


